# 2013 Workflow Continuously Restarts in 2019 Environment

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, workflow-settings

We are upgrading our 2013 on prem farm to 2019 on prem.  We've completed creating the 2019 farm and migrated the data using AvePoint, a migration tool.  I have a 2013 workflow that set to run on change but it continuously restarts itself on the 2019 farm.  It restarted 21 times in one minute and locks the item for editing while it's running.  Is there a setting we're missing?

In our 2013 farm, the 2013 workflows that are set to run on change will only run/be triggered if someone physically updates the item manually.  In other words if the system makes updates behind the scenes after the form is submitted the 2013 workflow is not triggered.

Comment: Adding this as a comment because it's just a shot in the dark, but did/do you have versioning enabled for the list in question?  I could see a migration tool doing something like stepping through each of the versions of an item from the old site and re-applying the changes to the item in the new site in order to re-create the version history.  That would end up being a significant amount of "updates" in a short amount of time from an account other than the system account (assuming the tool is not running as the system account).

Comment: Have you republished the workflows after the upgrade? I would give a vote to Dylan Cristy’s assumption of migration tool dealing with the item changes automatically at the background. You might want to switch the “Start workflow automatically when an item is changed” off for now and republish the workflow. Have the technical support of AvePoint to take a look if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Dylan and Chelsea for you replies.  Yes versioning was turned and I have republished the workflow. Even after that when I create new items on the list the workflow goes into a loop.  We did work with the AvePoint for weeks and they could not recreate the issue.  So my solution was to recreate a copy of the list and copy all the items over.  All is working fine now.